# convert param to upper case before posting to server through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Below is the method where i used toUpperCase() to convert params of my ajax function, but there are lots of function in my project and it is difficult for me to convert each param in uppercase.

How can i use $.ajaxSend global function of jquery to convert each param in to uppercase before it get posted to server.

```
$.ajax({
            url: isProductExistsURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            data: {
                locId: locId.toUpperCase(),
                prodId: prodId.toUpperCase(),
                suffix: suffix.toUpperCase()
            },
            success: function (exists) {
                if (exists) {
                    if (showInSummary) {
                        populateValidationSummaryWithCustomError(msg, 'Product');
                    }
                    else {
                        jAlert(msg, 'Alert', function () {
                            $(element).val('');
                            $(element).focus();
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (data, error, status) {
                debugger;
                alert("error ");
            },
            beforeSend: function (settings,jqXHR) {
                debugger;
                $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
                    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
                });
                $.blockUI();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
```

Comment: After giving you 2 correct answers and deleting them both since you keep drastically changing the requirements, I suggest you delete the above question and start again, but this time actually explain from the beginning what you are trying to do, rather than start at the end.

Comment: i have changed question content. not it will be easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is the last attempt.  I hope it's finally what you're looking for.

I've overridden the global `ajaxSend` event, as requested and have modified the querystring, setting all values to uppercase.  This will not work unless you are using GET, as you are in your example...

```
$(document).on("ajaxSend", function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    var url = ajaxOptions.url;
    if (url.search("\\?") == -1) return;
    var querystring = url.split("?")[1];
    url = url.split("?")[0];
    var split = querystring.split("&");
    querystring = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        var key = split[i].split("=")[0];
        var value = split[i].split("=")[1].toUpperCase();
        querystring += (querystring == "" ? "?" : "&") +
            key + "=" + value;
    }
    ajaxOptions.url = url + querystring;
});
```

Here's a working example.  Just check the console to see the URL, complete with querystring and uppercase values...

**[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/G7f6M/)**

Comment: i have used this code, ajaxOptions.url = ajaxOptions.url.toUpperCase();, but any way i have upvote and marked your reply as answer. Thanks to you @Archer

Comment: If you do that then it will change the variable names to uppercase as well.

Comment: Glad we finally got there :)

Comment: Asp.Net MVC maps param to controller method's without considering the case of param